# Change option dynamically in JQuery UI DatePicker fails

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to make date range selection using jquery-ui datepicker. First change at #dteStart succeed to set minDate at #dteEnd. 
But #dteEnd failed to refresh its options on next change, if i alert
`DateOptions.minDate` its value changed according to dateMin.

Maybe i miss something here...

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#dteStart").datepicker()
    .change(function () 
    {
        dateStart = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        dateMin = new Date(dateStart.getTime());
        dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + 1);

        var DateOptions = {
            dateformat: "mm/dd/yyyy",
            minDate: dateMin
        }
        $("#dteEnd").datepicker(DateOptions);
    });
});
```

TIA,

REV

Answer (score 32, accepted):

put `$("#dteEnd").datepicker("destroy");` before `$("#dteEnd").datepicker(DateOptions);` and it will work fine.

Comment: I wish i could give +2 to this answer!

Comment: those who use `datetimepicker` package try this which is working `$("#endDate").datetimepicker("destroy");`

Answer (score 26):

If you just want to change the already configured options, you can also do:

```
$("#dteEnd").datepicker("option", DateOptions);
```

or

```
$("#dteEnd").datepicker("option", { dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
```

Comment: For example: $( ".publishdatepicker" ).datepicker("option",{ yearRange: "-90:+1"});

Comment: Your second line, doesn't work with me, only when dateformat is dateFormat (with a capitalized F) 

jQueryUI 1.10.2

Comment: This second line was actually not from me, someone else put it in there. But I corrected it. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

The following jQuery helper function may be useful in such cases to preserve the original options:

```
$.fn.customizeDatepicker = function(newOptions) {
    var prevOptions = $(this).datepicker('option', 'all');
    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker($.extend(prevOptions, newOptions));
    return this;
};
```

It saves the previous options and extends them with the new options.

Answer (score 0):

$('#divbspDate').data("DateTimePicker").destroy();

You can try this, for Date time picker it is working.

Comment: Please apply code formating for the snippet