# How to change JQuery UI Date Picker option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a a jquery.ui datepicker.  I set it up like so:

```
 SetupDatepicker($(".date-three-field"), {   
        "buttonText": "Calendar",           
 });
```

Say, I later want to change the text of the button.  Based on this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373072/change-option-dynamically-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-fails),  I thought I could just do something like:

```
$("#id").datepicker('destroy');
$("#id").datepicker("option", { buttonText: "test" })
```

However, the text remains as 'calendar'.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call destroy. 
If you just want to change already configured option the second line is enough.

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", { buttonText: "test" });
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/2op25nfd/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but the answer is as follows:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "buttonText", "test" );
```

See https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonText for more info.