# jQuery UI datepicker - input invalid on load if using $('').datepicker('option', {})

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following simple form:

```
<form>
    <input name="default" type="date" required="required" /><br />
    <input name="maxDate" type="date" required="required" />
</form>
```

If I init the jQuery UI Datepicker plugin like this:

```
$('input[type=date]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
$('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker('option', {
    maxDate: 0
});
```

The second input with the extended options will be *invalid* on page load (see the attached [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bencergazda/90skeo8d/)), until I open the datepicker in it and set some values.

I checked the [Datepicker Widget API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option), but it looks to be the valid way to give extra option to the selected datepicker instance. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance :)

---

EDIT: Screenshot attached (FF 41)

[image]

Comment: what is the problem with jsfiddle, seems it's working fine?

Comment: `maxDate: 0` also working fine on second field.

Comment: You should change input type from date to text or use Modernizr or similar library to feature detect if the browser supports the input type=date, and then load the jQuery UI datepicker if if does not. Maybe you get confused that in some browsers html5 datepicker is upon the other one and you can't see it.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal Check it in Firefox; isn't the second input red at your browser? (See screenshot)

Comment: @calinaadi: Yes, it's the same also with `input type=text`.

Comment: The second input is red because of the requiered attribute not because it's something wrong with it.

Comment: @calinaadi That's true, it IS required. Both are required. :-) But it is RED not because it's required, but because `$('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker('option', {
    maxDate: 0
});` somehow makes it invalid. Try renaming the 2nd input so the `$('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker('option', ...)` cannot be executed.

Comment: You are initializing maxDate datePicker twice so second time you do it it's marked as changed so that's why the requiered validator is triggered. That  it was i was tring to say. I've noticed that both are requiered in the first place.

Comment: You can initialize them like this:$('input[name="default').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
$('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    maxDate: '0'
});

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939341/firefox-4-is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-red-border-in-a-required-form-input) is what you need. Please check!

Comment: @calinaadi Thank you. What I'd like to do is initalize Datepicker on _all_ `input[type=date]`, and set _custom options_ on some instances (like `input[name="maxDate"]`). Do you have maybe some idea if it's possible? Probably I've misunderstood how `.datepicker('option', {...})` works.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal Yes, it might be a way to solve the problem, thx :-)

Comment: If that's what you need as answer let me know I'll post it as an answer!

Comment: @DeepakBiswal Thank you, won't forget. But still would like to wait if a real solution arrives, 'cause removing the red borders rather just hides the problem than solves... :-)

Comment: You can call destroy and then reinitialize desired datepicker: $('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker("destroy");
$('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker({maxDate: 0,dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}); like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373072/change-option-dynamically-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-fails

Comment: @calinaadi Please post your last comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call destroy and then reinitialize desired datepicker:

`$('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker("destroy"); $('input[name="maxDate"]').datepicker({maxDate: 0,dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});`

like here: [Change option dynamically in JQuery UI DatePicker fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373072/change-option-dynamically-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-fails)

Comment: Thanks. Finally, i wrote the following function, based on your answer:
`$.fn.customizeDatepicker = function(newOptions) {
    var globalOptions = $(this).datepicker('option', 'all');
    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker($.extend(globalOptions, newOptions));
    return this;
};`